# useMemo error after building app with npm run-script build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-usememo, npm-build

After i use `npm run-script build` on my react site and run index.html browser throws error `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` on this part of code `{useMemo(() => <Tabulka/>, [bom,db,skipParams,columnNameMap,tableColumnOrder])}`. What should i do to make it work ?

Comment: Could you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and complete error message and stacktrace if it's available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually using useMemo from different library and no from React. Using React useMemo works.